# How to open the last folder irrespective of name on Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I’m currently working with a program that creates a folder with a time stamp and puts some files into it.

I want to write a script to automate retrieval of the file from last or second last folder by alphabetical order.

How do I do this on bash?

Image for reference. I want to retrieve a file from the 18-38 folder or the 17-45 folder.

[image]

Comment: 'last folder' is OS dependent and context dependent.

Comment: @dawg It's a cloud server. Context is the image I've attached. I don't want to manually go into the last created folder every time. If I could find a way to go into last folder (which is always the most recent one because of the timestamp) inside 2-Mar, I can save that file somewhere else, and use the script to move it to my local system and run some operations on it.

I want a way to use the last name on display when I do `ls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to write a script to automate retrieval of the file from last or second last folder by alphabetical order.

```
cd path/to/02-March-2022

last_dir=$(printf '%s\n' */ | sort | tail -n 1)
second_last_dir=$(printf '%s\n' */ | sort -r | sed '2!d; 2q')
```

- You can remove or add sort's `-r` to switch between Nth newest and Nth oldest.

Edit:

- Globs are always sorted alphabetically (according to current locale), so the first `sort` is actually superfluous. But `sort` is useful if you need the extra `sort` flags, or to sort by specific fields, suffixes, etc.
- Both `sort` and pathname expansion are affected by the current locale, so consider setting `LC_ALL=C` for consistent behavior. (`export LC_ALL=C` or `LC_ALL=C sort` for `sort` to see it).

Comment: Nice, but this does not filter out files...

Comment: If you mean targeting only directories and not files, it does: `*/` only matches (not hidden) directories. If you mean selecting OP's files in the newest directory, I'm not sure that was the point of the question.

Comment: @dan : Your command would break if one of the filenames contains a newline character.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, but here I think it's a reasonable assumption. Not fool proof though. You can use null delimiter if using GNU utilities: `'%s\0'`, and add `-z` to sort, tail, sed.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
folders=( path/to/02-March-2022/*/ )
last_dir=${folders[-1]%/}
second_last_dir=${folders[-2]%/}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to mine, I missed the bash tag on the question. I thought it was just `shell`. Unless I needed something other than alphabetical sort, I would use this.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have these directories:

```
% ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrew  wheel  64 Mar  3 15:19 1
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrew  wheel  64 Mar  3 15:19 2
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrew  wheel  64 Mar  3 15:19 3
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrew  wheel  64 Mar  3 15:19 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrew  wheel  64 Mar  3 15:19 5
```

With the 'last' being `5`.

You can do:

```
% for fn in *; do [[ -d "$fn" ]] && lf="$fn"; done
% echo "$lf"                                      
5
```

I cannot overstress, however, that the `*` **may** or **may not** give you what YOU think is the 'last directory.'

If you want to assure that it is the last one, sort them by `stat` and then take the last one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. Could you also please explain how this code works?

Comment: 1) `for fn in *` loop over the names in a directory; 2) `[[ -d "$fn" ]] && lf="$fn"` The first clause tests if the name is a directory or not and the second, only executed if the first is true, assigns the name to `$lf`; 3) Outide the loop - print the last directory seen

Answer (score 0):

Since globbing is, by default, alphabetically, I would load all the filenames into an array and pick the last element:

```
all_files=( * )
last_file=${all_files[-1]}
```

Two thinks are worth noting:

1. If the directory entries may be files or subdirectories, you will have to loop over `all_files` in reverse order and pick the first one which is a plain file.
2. You want to have them sorted alphabetically, but the **meaning** of this term, i.e. the [sort order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75341/specify-the-sort-order-with-lc-collate-so-lowercase-is-before-uppercase), depends on your environment - particular on the variable `LC_COLLATE`, respectively `LC_ALL`. You may want to set

i.e.:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

before creating the array.